# Please help me understand this python code line by line. I'm facing problem in understanding the flow of data in this code

Tags: python-3.x

```
def myfunc(z):
    return lambda x:x+1
t=myfunc(1)
print(t(2))
```

#I'm facing problem in understanding the flow of data in this code.

Comment: `myfunc` returns a function.  That function adds 1 to whatever it is passed.  After the assignment, it's just like you had said `def t(x):` / `return x+1`.

Answer (score 2):

A simplified explanation:

your definiton:

```py
def myfunc(z):
    return lambda x:x+1
t=myfunc(1)
print(t(2))
```

Is the same as (since you do not use z anywhere):

```py
def myfunc():
    return lambda x:x+1

t=myfunc()
print(t(2))
```

which is equivalent to:

```py
t = lambda x:x+1
print(t(2))
```

which is equivalent to:

```py
def t(x):
   return x+1

print(t(2))
```

and what it does, you assign the result of `myfunc`, which is a lambda (another function definition) to variable `t`

then you execute `t` with parameter `x` set to 2
which evaluates to 2+1 and returns 3